# In RxJava, I can't emit a onComplete from a flatMap

Tags: rx-java

I have the problem that my Observable chains don't terminate when I use a flatmap.

I've boiled down my example to this:

```
int count = Observable.just(1,2,3)
        .flatMap(s -> Observable.<Integer>create(subscr-> {
            subscr.onNext(s);
            if(s>2) {
                subscr.onCompleted();
            }
        }))
        .doOnEach(a->System.err.println(a.getKind()+" -> "+a.toString()))
        .count()
        .toBlocking()
        .first();
    System.err.println("Count: "+count);
```

I'd expect the 'doOnEach' to report three onNext events, followed by a onCompleted, and finally the chain should terminate.

However, the output is this:

```
OnNext -> [rx.Notification@c9e6d24d OnNext 1]
OnNext -> [rx.Notification@c9e6d24e OnNext 2]
OnNext -> [rx.Notification@c9e6d24f OnNext 3]
```

(and then in keeps hanging)

If I remove the flatMap operator:

```
int count = Observable.just(1,2,3)
        .doOnEach(a->System.err.println(a.getKind()+" -> "+a.toString()))
        .count()
        .toBlocking()
        .first();
System.err.println("Count: "+count);
```

... it works exactly as expected:

```
CREATED!
OnNext -> [rx.Notification@e3598bd9 OnNext 1]
OnNext -> [rx.Notification@e3598bda OnNext 2]
OnNext -> [rx.Notification@e3598bdb OnNext 3]
OnCompleted -> [rx.Notification@3834d63f OnCompleted]
Count: 3
```

I guess I am doing something wrong (I can't imagine a bug in such a basic scenario), but I don't see it.

Any help is appreciated... (I'm using RxJava 1.1.0)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue is in the following lines:

```
        if(s>2) {
            subscr.onCompleted();
        }
```

`Observable`s of `s == 1` and `s == 2` won't emit `onCompleted`. As `flatMap` only emits `onCompleted` when all `Observable`s are completed, it won't emit `onCompleted` in your case.

Comment: Aaahh, I have to complete every single flatmap invocation, en THEN it will complete. That explains it.

Comment: I also got stuck in this issue. FlatMap documentation explains why it is happening: "The FlatMap operator transforms an Observable by applying a function that you specify to each item emitted by the source Observable, where that function returns an Observable that itself emits items. FlatMap then merges the emissions of these resulting Observables, emitting these merged results as its own sequence."

Comment: "As flatMap only emits onCompleted when all Observables are completed", +1 for the tip, saved my life!